# Can you express the fraction 1/0 using imaginary units in any way possible?

Tags: number-theory

Although in basic textbooks, 1/0 is undefined or something along those lines, can it be expressed using complex numbers (i)? One way I propose is to use a function such as 1/x and use that function in imaginary units, but I am unsure as to how that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $1/0$ is not defined in the complex plane.

A fraction $a/b$ (for non-zero $b$) can be defined to be the unique solution for $x$ to the equation $b \cdot x = a$. The problem with defining $1/0$ is the same in the real numbers as it is in the complex numbers: the equation $0 \cdot x = 1$ has no solutions whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ approaches 0 from the right (resp. left), $1/x$ approaches positive (resp. negative) $\infty$.

If $z$ approaches 0 in modulus, $1/z$ approaches complex infinity, sometimes denoted $\tilde{\infty}$.

I'm not 100% sure if I understand your question is, or if the above answers it.